# Broken alsa-lib and missing alsa.conf

Tags: sound, alsa

Recently I started to learn about ALSA. I wanted to start with examples so I installed the alsa-lib-1.2.4 from https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Download.
That caused the problems with the programs that uses ALSA lib so I uninstalled alsa-lib package.

I tried to install alsa-lib back by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

but I get:

```
libasound2 is already the newest version (1.1.3-5ubuntu0.5).
```

Also, there is no `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` file.

If I run speaker-test I get the following:

```
speaker-test -c 2

sspeaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib conf.c:3916:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

```
aplay -L | grep :CARD
ALSA lib conf.c:3916:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa0430000 irq 169
```

How can I reinstall alsa-lib to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the following re-installation fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libasound2 libasound2-data libasound2-plugins
```